# Can not get data from form in Node.js using express

Tags: node.js, forms, express

I am building a small app that inputs movie name from the user and sends a request to an API that then sends the rating of that movie.
When I input the name of the movie in a form, that form submits to `/movie-data` (a get request) which I will eventually use to fire off an request to the API, but the problem is that I can not get the data that has been input by the user in the form.
Here is my app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 4000 || process.env.PORT;

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.get("", (req, res) => {
  res.render("index");
});

app.get("/movie-data", (req, res) => {
  try {
    const name = req.body.movieName;   //undefined here
    console.log(name);
    res.redirect("/");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.sendStatus(500);
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("Server running on port ${port}");
});
```

In the `app.get("/movie-data"..` request handler when i try to get the name of the movie it is undefined.
Here is my HTML form.

```
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Movie Name</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="movieName"
            required
            class="form-control"
            id="name"
          />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-4">Find</button>
      </form>
```

According to my understanding a server could access a certain field of the form by the name defined in the input field like in the above HTML code I have defined `name="movieName"`

Comment: `app.get`'s wont have `req.body` as its the body of a POST

Comment: So i should use app.post?

Comment: your prob need both, get for get and post for handling your form

Comment: Ok so I did a bit of research and I think in a get request I would get data using req.query.. right?

Comment: yeah if this is a search form then .get is the correct type to use, to access the params which get put on the url i.e `?movieName=Goonies` it would be like `req.query.movieName`, yup

Comment: Can you please add the opening `<form ...>` tag.

Comment: hey @Daniel, thanks for your comment.. I actually solved the problem by using `req.query.movieName`..
Here's the opening tag of the form
`<form action="/movie-data" method=GET>..`